Solana tool building
We are building the mini-app with the website for it. Our main goal for the website is to filter and sort among tokens on the Solana blockchain from the Admin Panel and display the most relevant collections of tokens for users on the website.
We looked at your API and while it has a tokens list endpoint there are no filters and sorting can be done only by 24-hour period. Even though, there are applications that provide trends for 30-minute periods and claim that they are powered by BirdEye.
So we assume that there is some missing information in the documentation or we need to go through some integration process. Either way, we will be glad to collaborate with you.
Many thanks for considering my request.
Maksym Livak
